# Using TCP connection to execute parallel threads over different ports

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp

I am trying to execute this python script for implementing a distributed computing protocol. Currently this executes the functions sequentially one after the other. i want to be able to run all the processes parallel on different ports instead of the ** multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()** as has been mentioned in the statement below but i have no clue how should i go about. Any head start would be appreciated to lead me in the right direction

```
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread

class Process(Thread):
  def __init__(self, env, id):
    super(Process, self).__init__()
    self.inbox = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    self.env = env
    self.id = id

  def run(self):
    try:
      self.body()
      self.env.removeProc(self.id)
    except EOFError:
      print "Exiting.."

  def getNextMessage(self):
    return self.inbox.get()

  def sendMessage(self, dst, msg):
    self.env.sendMessage(dst, msg)

  def deliver(self, msg):
    self.inbox.put(msg)
```

Comment: And what are you asking here? For us to modify the code for you?

Comment: @duskwuff no. just to give an idea of how should i modify the code. I am relatively new to threading so not sure how to move ahead although i know that i have to deal with sockets and ports to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to run this code in parallel mode by implementing simple socket programming instead of Queues by following the python documentation and then making the communication of messages possible over those sockets.